# Fluent Rest configuration in Camel 2.14.0

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, dsl

I am using the new rest component from 2.14.0 in Camel, and using the following configuration:

```
DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

RestConfiguration rc = new RestConfiguration();
rc.setComponent("spark-rest");
rc.setPort(9091);
context.setRestConfiguration(rc);
```

In the [rest-dsl page](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html), there are references showing a way to configure rest with the fluent dsl, like:

```
restConfiguration()
 .component("restlet")
 .host("localhost")
 .port(portNum)
 .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
```

But I cannot seem to find where the proper placeholder to add this to.

In short, the camel documentation shows a way to use the fluent DSL to configure the Camel context, but I cannot find where/how to do it.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally for the spark needed to get this placed properly. That was in the route builder configure method.

```
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
  return new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
      restConfiguration()
      .component("spark-rest")
      .port(9091);
```